# Will vine survive after this?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, vines

I have this vine that grew out of a pot, and it’s been wrapping around things.

Then yesterday somebody kicked the pot and the vine “broke” (if that’s the word).

I just stuck the end back in the soil, but as you can see, the leaves are starting to droop.

Will it survive after this?
[image]

Comment: when you say 'vine' what plant is it? How big a pot is it in, how long;s it been there?

Comment: It’s in a small pot, and it’s been growing a few weeks.

Comment: It would depend on the type of plant.  Some vine will regrow from the roots, if it is cut to the ground.  Others will not.

Comment: Would you be able to identify the plant if I took a picture of the leaves?

Comment: The pot came with a flower (that’s why I bought it). A few weeks later (after the flower had died) I notice the vine growing.

Comment: we do  need to know which plant it is - what was the flower like, if you don't know the name> The leaves in their current state are hard to ID

Answer (score 1):

From the description, I assume the stem broke from the base and detached from the roots.

Normally rooting in a "wet" box (covered to retain moisture) is ideal, especially that the leaves are already wilted. You may resort to rooting it in water (while also covered to retain moisture) for best results.

If a stump was left above the ground, where the stem broke-off, there is a chance it will leaf-out again and regrow. Don't give up on this one yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks very unhappy and critically thirsty.

If the plant has been "broken" from the roots then it will need to be treated differently.

It should be put in cup of water so that it can grow new roots and only then should it be placed in a pot.

[Propagation methods](https://www.gardenista.com/posts/houseplants-101-how-to-propagate-cuttings-roots-leaves/)

Not easy for a beginner but very achievable when done correctly.